# Test configuration service throwing NPE

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, integration-testing, junit4

I'm struggling with integration test writing, I want to test my service which is communicating with a JPA repository and it seems that I made a mistake as the test won't run and throws an NPE on my service.

My app is running on a springboot configuration (nothing fishy with weird dependencies, I wanted to stay as stock as possible to avoid side effects).

My service manages users and is really simplistic:
- autowired repository
- one method calling the repository (i wanted to make the test run before adding the control logic)

```
@Service
public class ApplicationUserService{

@Autowired
private ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;

public ApplicationUser getUserByFirstname(String firstnameToLookFor){
    return this.applicationUserRepository.findByFirstname ( 
    firstnameToLookFor );

}
}
```

The repository is also as simple :

```
public interface ApplicationUserRepository extends 
JpaRepository<ApplicationUser, Integer> {

// ...

ApplicationUser findByFirstname(String firstname);
}
```

And finally my test which as the two other elements is really simple :

```
@RunWith (SpringRunner.class)
public class UserServiceIntegrationTest {

@TestConfiguration
static class UserServiceTestContextConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ApplicationUserService applicationUserService(){

        return new ApplicationUserService ();
    }
}

@Autowired
private ApplicationUserService applicationUserService;

@MockBean
private ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;


@Before
public void setup(){
    ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser ("darky", "bruce@wayne.com", 
"iLoveSelin4", "Bruce", "WAYNE", "en");

    Mockito.when (applicationUserRepository.findByFirstname ( 
user.getUsername () )).thenReturn ( user );
}

@Test
public void getUserByFirstName() {
    String firstnameToLook = "Bruce";
    ApplicationUser userFound = applicationUserService.getUserByFirstname ( 
firstnameToLook );
    assertThat(userFound.getFirstname ()).isEqualTo ( firstnameToLook );
}

}
```

Supposedly, the test has to be ok.
But as said before i have a NPE thrown on the assert `assertThat(userFound.getFirstname ()).isEqualTo ( firstnameToLook );`, and when i debug on the line just above the assert i can see that `applicationUserService` is null.

What am I doing wrong in here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When `applicationUserService` is null the NPE should be in this line: `applicationUserService.getUserByFirstname ( 
firstnameToLook );`. But when the NPE is in line `assertThat(userFound.getFirstname ()).isEqualTo ( firstnameToLook );` than i think your mock is wrong an `userFound` is null.

Comment: You dont mock `.findAll ()` or? What is the outcome when you log `userfound` is it null? Or is the NPE before?

Comment: Indeed that was my mock ...

`    Mockito.when (applicationUserRepository.findByFirstname ( 
user.getUsername () )).thenReturn ( user );
}`

Was looking for the firstname while using the username T_T

Thanks